# $(body).css({'background-image':'url'}) not working

Tags: jquery, background-image, css

Shall I assume that I can't apply `.css()` to the body tag?

Because if I do it on `$("#div")`... it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document.body).css(...)
```

or

```
$('body').css(...)
```

Comment: very very very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253838/need-to-apply-those-styles-using-css-jquery-function-help-needed :)

Comment: For the confused: $(document.body).css('background-color', 'DDDCCC') - gives me -> .css is not a function in both Firebug and Dragonfly (Opera's console) on some sites. Because document.body must be returning a js object not a jquery one - I'm guessing it's because of frames but I stopped before getting to the bottom of it

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
$("body").css("background-image","url('/my/image.jpg')");
```

Comment: yup, it's same solution,, but thanks! oh no, ',' VS ':' ..i allways used ':'.. hm..