# Need to apply those Styles using .css() Jquery Function, help needed

Tags: jquery, css, background

this is the style i need

```
body{
      background: url("img/Background_Home.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;


      margin:0;
    }
```

And this is my go..

```
 function actualizar_fondo(imagen){
            $('body').css({"background":"url(img/"+imagen+".jpg)"});
            $('body').css({"background":"no-repeat center center fixed"});
            $('body').css({"-webkit-background-size":"cover"});
            $('body').css({"-moz-background-size":"cover"});
            $('body').css({"-o-background-size":"cover"});
            $('body').css({"background-size":"cover"});



       }
```

Result: Not even background image (but with only first line, works)

i guess... problems are in second line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second line is overiding the result of first line. Both can be combined.

```
function actualizar_fondo(imagen){
        $('body').css({"background":"url(img/"+imagen+".jpg) no-repeat center center fixed"});
        $('body').css({"-webkit-background-size":"cover"});
        $('body').css({"-moz-background-size":"cover"});
        $('body').css({"-o-background-size":"cover"});
        $('body').css({"background-size":"cover"});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How in three answers do you not already have this?

```
$('body').css({
    "background": "url(img/"+imagen+".jpg) no-repeat center center fixed",
    "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
    "-moz-background-size": "cover",
    "-o-background-size": "cover",
    "background-size": "cover"
});
```

Are you sure you can't just do:

```
.myClass {
    background: url("img/Background_Home.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

with:

```
$('body').addClass('myClass');
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function actualizar_fondo(imagen){
        $('body').css("background", "url(img/"+imagen+".jpg) no-repeat center center fixed");
        $('body').css("-webkit-background-size","cover");
        $('body').css("-moz-background-size","cover");
        $('body').css("-o-background-size","cover");
        $('body').css("background-size","cover");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second background declaration is overiding the result of first line - you need to combine them both.  I'd also recommend combining all of the [CSS declarations into a single JSON map](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2):

```
function actualizar_fondo(imagen){
    $('body').css(
       { "background":"url(img/" + imagen + ".jpg) no-repeat center center fixed",
         "-webkit-background-size":"cover",
         "-moz-background-size":"cover",
         "-o-background-size":"cover",
         "background-size":"cover" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try using the distinct background properties:

```
function actualizar_fondo(imagen){
            $('body').css({"background-image":"url(img/"+imagen+".jpg)",
                           "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
                           "background-position":"center center",
                           "background-attachment":"fixed",
                           "-webkit-background-size":"cover",
                           "-moz-background-size":"cover",
                           "-o-background-size":"cover",
                           "background-size":"cover"});
       }
```

Probably you are overiding the background one in the second line of your 'actualizar_fondo' function.