# Jquery document.body.background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, deprecated

I'm having some trouble with a jquery script that is supposed to change my body element's background image when a link is pressed. It works great, the only problem I have is that the page has to have no background set in CSS, and be blank before any link is pressed, wich changes the background.  The jquery this uses is really old, tried newer versions but nothing works except this one. Also, I've tried `document.body.style.backgroundImage` , still no success, this is maybe because of the old version this script uses.  Could you figure out what's wrong here ?

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--

    // Copyright 2001 by www.CodeBelly.com
    // Please do *not* remove this notice.

    var backImage = new Array(); // don't change this

    // Enter the image filenames you wish to use.
    // Follow the pattern to use more images.  The
    // number in the brackets [] is the number you
    // will use in the function call to pick each
    // image.

    // Note how backImage[3] = "" -- which would
    // set the page to *no* background image.

    backImage[0] = "img/1.jpg";
    backImage[1] = "img/2.jpg";
    backImage[2] = "img/3.jpg";
    backImage[3] = "img/4.jpg";
    backImage[4] = "img/5.jpg";
    backImage[5] = "img/3.jpg";
    backImage[6] = "img/4.jpg";
    backImage[7] = "img/5.jpg";
    backImage[8] = "img/3.jpg";
    backImage[9] = "img/1.jpg";
    //-----------------------------

    function changeBGImage(whichImage){
    if (document.body){
    document.body.background = backImage[whichImage];

    }
    }

    //-->
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
```

Comment: try this `document.body.style.background`

Comment: i don't see any jQuery code anywhere......???

Comment: You need to set it the same way in js as you would do in css. So you need a `url()` around your image url.

Comment: Already on Stack Overflow. Read the answers to this question below.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253718/body-cssbackground-imageurl-not-working][1]

Hope this helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253718/body-cssbackground-imageurl-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code of line should work for you:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + backImage[whichImage] + ')');
```

Comment: I was happy to help :). Please, feel free to mark the answer as the correct one if it helped you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('body').css('background-image','url("source of your image")');
```

Comment: Please improve your answer so it at least contains what you think is wrong  in the OP-code and why you think your suggestion would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

By JS itself, try this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[index]+')'
```